# HTML2Canvas creating multiple divs

Tags: jspdf, html2canvas

I'm trying to create a PDF using jsPDF and HTML2Canvas.
I have multiple DIVs to insert into the PDF. 
If I try to put all DIVs into a container and render once then it only puts the first page height into the PDF. 
Can't figure out how to render multiple divs and stick them in the same PDF so that it keeps going page by page.

JAVASCRIPT

```js
function genPDF() {         
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("container"), {

        onrendered: function (canvas) {

            var img = canvas.toDataURL();

            var doc = new jsPDF(); 
            doc.addImage(img, 'PNG');
            doc.addPage(); 

            doc.save('test.pdf');
        }
    });
}
```

HTML

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="divEl" id="div1">Hi <img  src="img1.JPG"> </div>
    <div class="divEl" id="div2">Why <img  src="img2.PNG"> </div>
</div>

<button onClick="genPDF()"> Click Me </button>
```

Answer (score 12):

Add each of your images separately.
You need to wait for all the html2canvas renderings are done and added to pdf and then save your final pdf.

One way to achieve this by using JQuery and array of promises, actual code would look like this:

```js
function genPDF() { 
    var deferreds = [];
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfInnerDivs; i++) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        deferreds.push(deferred.promise());
        generateCanvas(i, doc, deferred);
    }

    $.when.apply($, deferreds).then(function () { // executes after adding all images
      doc.save('test.pdf');
    });
}

function generateCanvas(i, doc, deferred){

    html2canvas(document.getElementById("div" + i), {

        onrendered: function (canvas) {

            var img = canvas.toDataURL();
            doc.addImage(img, 'PNG');
            doc.addPage(); 

            deferred.resolve();
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks but you'll have to excuse my inexperience. I'm a very new coder. 
So, I'm grabbing form elements and adding them into divs. So how can I know the numberOfInnerDivs?

Comment: This is a teaching tool for language teachers

I have elements like:
`<div id="Present-Insert"></div>`
`<div id="Past-Insert"></div>` 
etc... are already in the code and I'm adding divs into these based on which grammar element they're associated with. 

How can I count how many are inserted in order to pass that into the function?

Comment: To count number of divs you want to iterate, you can use the JQuery .length property
var numberOfInnerDivs = $('.divEl').length;

Comment: Or to count how many divs inside other div you can use:
You can use jQuery.children property.

var numberOfInnerDivs = $('.Present-Insert').children('div').length;

Answer (score 0):

For me it works like that:

```
$('#cmd2').click(function () {

    var len = 4; //$x(".//body/div/div").length
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm','a4');
    var position = 0;
    Hide
    for (let i = 1;i  <= len; i++){
        html2canvas(document.querySelector('#pg'+i),
            {dpi: 300, // Set to 300 DPI
            scale: 1 // Adjusts your resolution
            }).then(canvas => {
            pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("images/png", 1), 'PNG', 0,position, 210, 295);

            if (i == len){
                pdf.save('sample-file.pdf');
            }else{
                pdf.addPage();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: what does the 'Hide' on line 5 stands for?

Comment: This will add pages without your desired order. Asyncrony does that, depending on workload light pages will go first.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, using the follwing javascript references in the HTML. Html2Canvas and jsPDF are quite picky with versions you use.

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"

```
var forPDF = document.querySelectorAll(".js-panel-pdf");
var len = forPDF.length;
var thisPDF = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', [240, 210]); //210mm wide and 297mm high

for (var i = 0; i < forPDF.length; i++) {
html2canvas(forPDF[i], {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        thisPDF.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("images/png", 1), 'PNG', 0, 0, 210, 295);
        if (parseInt(i + 1) === len) {
            thisPDF.save('sample-file.pdf');
        } else {
            thisPDF.addPage();
        }
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Stuart Smith  - This is not working it does not allow to download the pdf

here is  java script  code

```
function generatePDF(){
        var imgData;
        var forPDF = document.querySelectorAll(".summary");
        var len `enter code here`= forPDF.length;
        var doc =new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
        for (var i = 0; i < forPDF.length; i++){
            html2canvas(forPDF[i],{
            useCORS:true,
            onrendered:function(canvas){
            imgData =  canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg',1.0);
            var doc =new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
            doc.addImage(imgData,'jpg',10,10,500,480);
            if (parseInt(i + 1) === len) {
        doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
    } else {
        doc.addPage();
    }
            

        }
    });
    

}
```

}